# SSRS Chart - X Axis Labels not displaying correct values in Scalar Mode and Logarithmic Scale

Tags: reporting-services, charts

My dataset is as follows:
[image: Tamis is the X-Axis and Value1 to Value8 are the Y-Axis]

I use the scalar axis type on the X-Axis for having a logarithmic scale but then the X-Axis labels do not display the correct Values of my 'Tamis' column from my dataset:
[image: Chart rendering]

Especially 0.0625 in chart instead of 0.063 in dataset.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override this, change the axis properties.

For example you could change the minimum property to

```
=MIN(Fields!Tamis.Value)
```

Comment: It doesn't work as expected, the first X value is correct now but all the other ones are incorrect.

Comment: edit your post snd show what you expect to see, even in the original image you posted I can't what the problem is, the axis values look fine.